# Why the es get idf value is 0.30685282?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I get result from Explain API

```
{
    "took": 5,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 0.13424811,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_shard": 2,
                "_node": "Tf1RSzMxQD-AYhmnKQWr8Q",
                "_index": "scoretest",
                "_type": "test",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.13424811,
                "_source": {
                    "content": "this book is about english",
                    "title": "this is a book"
                },
                "_explanation": {
                    "value": 0.13424811,
                    "description": "weight(content:english in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "value": 0.13424811,
                            "description": "fieldWeight in 0, product of:",
                            "details": [
                                {
                                    "value": 1,
                                    "description": "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                                    "details": [
                                        {
                                            "value": 1,
                                            "description": "termFreq=1.0"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": 0.30685282,
                                    "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": 0.4375,
                                    "description": "fieldNorm(doc=0)"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here I do not understand two point:

1 The formual of idf is :

```
  public float idf(long docFreq, long numDocs) {
    return (float)(Math.log(numDocs/(double)(docFreq+1)) + 1.0);
  }
```

why docFreq is 1 and numDocs is 1 will got idf value to be 0.30685282?

```
log(0.5) = -0.3010299957 + 1.0 = 0.6989700043
```

2 the numDocs is 1？

Does numDocs mean how many docs in my index? I have 2 docs in my index, why it use 1?

about question two, see this query result:

```
{
    "took": 17,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 0.13424811,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_shard": 2,
                "_node": "Tf1RSzMxQD-AYhmnKQWr8Q",
                "_index": "scoretest",
                "_type": "test",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.13424811,
                "_source": {
                    "content": "this book is about english",
                    "title": "this is a book"
                },
                "_explanation": {
                    "value": 0.13424811,
                    "description": "weight(content:book in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "value": 0.13424811,
                            "description": "fieldWeight in 0, product of:",
                            "details": [
                                {
                                    "value": 1,
                                    "description": "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                                    "details": [
                                        {
                                            "value": 1,
                                            "description": "termFreq=1.0"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": 0.30685282,
                                    "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": 0.4375,
                                    "description": "fieldNorm(doc=0)"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_shard": 3,
                "_node": "Tf1RSzMxQD-AYhmnKQWr8Q",
                "_index": "scoretest",
                "_type": "test",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.13424811,
                "_source": {
                    "content": "this book is about chinese",
                    "title": "this is a book"
                },
                "_explanation": {
                    "value": 0.13424811,
                    "description": "weight(content:book in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "value": 0.13424811,
                            "description": "fieldWeight in 0, product of:",
                            "details": [
                                {
                                    "value": 1,
                                    "description": "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
                                    "details": [
                                        {
                                            "value": 1,
                                            "description": "termFreq=1.0"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": 0.30685282,
                                    "description": "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": 0.4375,
                                    "description": "fieldNorm(doc=0)"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Natural log, not base 10.  1+ln(1/(1+1)) = 0.30685282
2. Yes, it is the number of documents in the index.  However, the documents in your index appear to be in different *shards*, which are effectively separate indexes, at least as far as the doc count for scoring is concerned.  You can read a bit more about this on Jeroen van Wilgenburg's blog:  [How sharding in elasticsearch makes scoring a little less accurate and what to do about it](https://vanwilgenburg.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/scoring-and-sharding-in-elasticsearch/).  I think it bears emphasizing one line in his conclusion though:  "With larger sets the score differences will converge."

Comment: first question i got the answer, but the second one, i call _flush to flush the document, the numDocs still be one

Comment: please see question append, i call a query, it return two document, but the numDocs still 1....

Comment: @jianfeng - Think I see what the actual problem there is now, I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I set shard to be 1 and the maxDocs will changed to be 2. It indeed the reason